# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' and i donno whats wrong o.o

Tags: php, html, sql

when i run the following i get parse error. im a noob btw

```
   <?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `as_questions`(`Qid`, `M_class`, `S_class`,`Question`, `Answer`, `Doctor`, `Time`) VALUES
('n','n','n','q','a','d','')";?>
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing `)`, i.e. `mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `as_questions`(`Qid`, `M_class`, `S_class`, `Question`, `Answer`, `Doctor`, `Time`) VALUES
('n','n','n','q','a','d','')");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot )

```
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");
//Sending form data to sql db.
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `as_questions`(`Qid`, `M_class`, `S_class`, `Question`, `Answer`, `Doctor`, `Time`) VALUES
('n','n','n','q','a','d','')");
```